# phantom language switcher

Tags: multi-language, plugin-polylang

Some background,

I had an english installation of wordpress, with ENFOLD theme. (not my doing)
the original developer installed polylang and turned it to multi-language site (two languages).

I've been asked (i'm not a WP developer) to split it to two websites, one for each language. so i've installed wp in another language and imported the database - and then, changed the language.

i removed the polylang plugin.

however, now, the fifth element of the menu, where the original language switcher was set, is now shoen always as a flag.. tho it points to the correct url.

how can i rmove it?

Comment: It is not the Polylang switcher. More likely it is a custom menu item. Login to the admin area and edit the menu.

Comment: that's what i did.
i'm adding a page/post/custom-link - all of them points to the correct location, but shown as a flag.

Comment: Then you have to scrutinize `functions.php` and CSS files to figure out where it comes from.